# Removing a tab after it is created if certain conditions are true

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am just starting o use the chrome.(something) commands and I am not really sure what proper syntax would be regarding them. What I am trying to do here is frist of all a test of concept, basically if the  new tab that was created matches a specific url (in this case only facebook but I want it to be more than just one page.) then it should close that tab. I am not really sure how to write that but I think I have an idea and I would like for someone to explain the corrections that were made so I can understand. Thanks.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab.url){
if (tab.url===*://facebook.com/*){
chrome.tabs.remove(tab)
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('facebook.com') != -1) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
    }
});
```

If you want to be more precise about the URL matching, I suggest that you parse the URL instead of doing string matching or using regular expressions.

Here's a simple way to do it using an `a` tag: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: How could I manage for example if I wanted to do this for multiple URLs instead of just 1 like the example?

Comment: Perhaps I could do what it says and then make it go through an array of objects that have the info? And to make them make a custom constructor?

Comment: @Zero Yes, you could be using an array, but constructors have nothing to do with that? Do you mean the `Array` constructor?

Comment: I meant more like the constructor for objects. But could you take a look at this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4dcdfeeaa83221c6cafb